# Mostrar fecha de modificación en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando mostrar en mis entradas de WordPress la fecha de modificación de un post, siempre que este haya sido modificado claro.

Buscando por la red he encontrado este código en StackExchange:

```php
if ( get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) > get_the_time( 'U' ) ) {
    echo 'Last updated:' . get_the_modified_time();
}
```

Adaptándolo, lo he incorporado así a mi `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'sp_post_info_filter' );
function sp_post_info_filter($post_info) {
if ( is_single() ) {
    $post_info = 'Por [post_author_posts_link] | Fecha de publicación: [post_date]';
    if ( get_the_modified_date( 'U' ) > get_the_date( 'U' ) ) {
        //echo 'Last updated:' . get_the_modified_time();
        $post_info .= 'Modificado: ' . get_the_modified_date();
    }
    return $post_info;
}}
```

El problema es que siempre muestra la fecha modificada, aunque la entrada no haya sido cambiada.

¿Cómo podría afinarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, tras una serie de comprobaciones y cambios, he conseguido obtener lo deseado. El problema era que tanto `get_the_modified_time()` como `get_the_time()` estaban devolviendo un tipo String, por lo que he capturado esos valores en variables y posteriormente he procedido a pasarlas a tipo `date`.

```php
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'sp_post_info_filter' );
function sp_post_info_filter($post_info) {
if ( is_single() ) {
    $post_info = '';
    $modifica = get_the_modified_date('U');
    $publica = get_the_date('U');
    $modifica2 = date('Y-m-d',$modifica);
    $publica2 = date('Y-m-d',$publica);

    if ( $modifica2 > $publica2 ){
        $post_info .= '<div class="modificada">Esta publicación fue actualizada el ' . get_the_modified_date() . '</div>';
    }

    return $post_info;
}
```